# What is the easiest way to handle magic quotes in PHP while migrating from 5.3 to 5.6?

Tags: php, php-5.3, php-5.6

I've thousands of queries in my codebase that don't use binding and rely on magic quotes (it is a 10 year old codebase). Is there a sane, easy way to handle it while upgrading from 5.3 to 5.6? I understand the best long term solution is find all these queries and using binding, but I'm just looking for any other way until it can be done.